# fillna by selected rows in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have next pandas DataFrame:

```
a b c 
1 1 5.0
1 1 None
1 1 4.0
1 2 1.0
1 2 1.0
1 2 4.0 
2 1 3.0
2 1 2.0
2 1 None
2 2 3.0
2 2 4.0
```

I want to replace `None`, but not by the column mean. I want to select all rows, where the values in `a` and `b` are similar and if `c` has a `None`-values in selected rows, replace them only with the `c`-mean of selected rows. Something like (this code doesn't work):

```
df[df[('a'==1) & ('b'==1)]]['c'].fillna(df[df[('a'==1) & ('b'==1)]]['c'].mean())
```

which should get me the output:

```
a b c 
1 1 5.0
1 1 4.5
1 1 4.0
1 2 1.0
1 2 1.0
1 2 4.0 
2 1 3.0
2 1 2.0
2 1 None
2 2 3.0
2 2 4.0
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need filter values of `c` by conditions and assign back column `c`:

```
mask = (df['a']==1) & (df['b']==1)
mean = df.loc[mask, 'c'].mean()
df.loc[mask, 'c'] = df.loc[mask, 'c'].fillna(mean)
```

Or use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for replace by conditions:

```
df['c'] = df['c'].mask(mask, df['c'].fillna(mean))
#similar
#df['c'] = np.where(mask, df['c'].fillna(mean), df['c'])

print (df)
    a  b    c
0   1  1  5.0
1   1  1  4.5
2   1  1  4.0
3   1  2  1.0
4   1  2  1.0
5   1  2  4.0
6   2  1  3.0
7   2  1  2.0
8   2  1  NaN
9   2  2  3.0
10  2  2  4.0
```

Comment: What if the input df has a NaN where the 'a' and 'b' values match other than 1, say for example 'a' =2 and 'b' =2

Comment: @prabhakar - There is no `NaN`, so no replace. But maybe missing, what you think. Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael, you are right. Not all combination of values from a and b should have NaN values. Only values in random rows...

Comment: My doubt is out of the question. Just a bit curious to know if there is such 'NaN' in the input, with 'a' and 'b' equal to 2. Sorry to bother you.