# Fill a column in a DataFrame for a specific condition of other column

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to do something like this:  `qc_data` is my dataframe (pandas ), `PH` is one of the values in column `NEW_QC_TEST`. How do I do this correctly?

```
qc_data[qc_data['NEW_QC_TEST'] == "PH"]["VALUE"].fillna(6.9, inplace=True)
```

I did try the following but is even worse I think

```
#qc_data[qc_data['NEW_QC_TEST'] == "PH"].isnull().sum()
#qc_data[qc_data['NEW_QC_TEST'] == "PH"].fillna(6.9, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Are you using Pandas? Please [edit] and add the tag for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a filter like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
qc_data = pd.DataFrame(data={'NEW_QC_TEST': [1, "PH"], 'VALUE': [2, np.nan]})
qc_data.loc[(qc_data['NEW_QC_TEST'] == "PH") & qc_data['VALUE'].isna(), "VALUE"] = 6.9
print(qc_data)
```

Which produces the following:

```
  NEW_QC_TEST  VALUE
0           1    2.0
1          PH    6.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Most intuitively, you would expect this to work:

**❌ Wrong approach:**

```
qc_data[qc_data['NEW_QC_TEST'] == "PH"]["VALUE"].fillna(6.9, inplace=True)
```

But it **does not work** because of *chained-indexing*, I won't dive into the details, but in short, this returns a copy on which `fillna` acts in place, so original data stays intact. See links below for more explanations.

**✅ Right approach:**

Select the part you need and assign `fillna` results into it:

```
rows_mask = qc_data['NEW_QC_TEST'] == "PH"
qc_data.loc[rows_mask, "VALUE"] = qc_data.loc[rows_mask, "VALUE"].fillna(6.9)
```

**More explanations**

- Pandas docs on chained-indexing [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=view%20versus%20copy#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).
- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11984
- [fillna by selected rows in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963491/fillna-by-selected-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)
- [Pandas won't fillna() inplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998354/pandas-wont-fillna-inplace)